# Images not getting loaded when Website deployed to IIS

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4

The images used in the website are stored here (in the Images folder) -

[image: Document Tree]

And the images are referenced this way -

```
<img src="@Url.Content("/Images/greenDot.png")" style="margin-right: 10px;"/>
```

When I run the website on my local machine, all the images get loaded fine. But when I deploy it on IIS and run that website none of the images get loaded.

Errors -

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found) http://54.234.60.214/Images/Logo_Innosolv.jpg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://54.234.60.214/Images/Icons/bid.png
```

What seems to be the problem? Do I move the images to some other folder or do I change the way I reference them in the views?

Comment: file permission issue? does everyone have read access?

Comment: What is your `parent directory` for all this content shown in above figure?

Comment: Yup, everyone's got read permission to all the project files.

Comment: @mridula What errors can you see in the console? `404 Not Found` for images only?

Comment: yes. that's the only error.

Comment: In May 2018, we faced a similar issue that only occured when we deployed our ASP.Net MVC 5 application to Azure.  The solution was to use @Url.Content() for the src.  Notice the use of single-quotes and double-quotes, which is unlike other examples:

<img src='@Url.Content("~/images/Default/header-logo.png")' alt="Header logo" title="Header logo"/>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the ~ sign in your path to the image.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/greenDot.png")" style="margin-right: 10px;"/>
```

If you have authentication in your website, check if the path to the folder has public rights. You must do this in your web.config.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware that the website was deployed as a web app under an already existing website. 
So the images should have been fetched from

```
http://54.234.60.214/IBeam_2/Images/Logo_Innosolv.jpg
```

Instead of -

```
http://54.234.60.214/Images/Logo_Innosolv.jpg
```

So, I changed the path to

```
<img src="~/Images/Logo_Innosolv.jpg" style="margin-right: 10px;"/>
```

It is working now.

Comment: but i load images in css as url(Images/some.jpg) here i cant use tilde. :(

Comment: I was using the following in a css file: `background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");` (bootstrap) and in order to make it work after publishing, I had to move the `img` folder to the `Content` folder as it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I change the way I reference them in the views?

Yes, off course you should change the path of the images according to your deployment directory structure. Check if you have added the correct relative or absolute path whichever be right with your website.

**OR**

May be you have not enabled your IIS to show images. You can do that as specified in [this link](http://peterkellner.net/2008/04/01/iis7imageproblem/)

If you are loading the images with css , then you must check if that was the path problem.